# Selecting specific values from list within a list that has been imported from another python file (CONSTRAINTS ON WHAT I CAN EDIT)

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Having trouble selecting specific values from list within a list that's being imported from another python file. I keep getting the error `IndexError: list index out of range`. Usually I would just assign the returned value from the list to another variable outside the function in the other folder thus making it global however I have a couple constraints:

1. I cannot change the list within a list file in any way (data_source.py).
2. I also cannot change the function that calls my dataset earlier in my code.

The dataset displays the following list in my shell window:

```
Using random number seed 2849 ...

The moves to visualise are:
[[0, 7, 'North'],
 [1, 'Move & turn right'],
 [2, 'Move forward'],
 [3, 'Move & turn left'],
 [4, 'Move forward'],
 [5, 'Move forward'],
 [6, 'Move & turn right'],
 [7, 'Move forward']]
```

My current code stands as such:

IMPORTED FILE CODE (CANNOT EDIT OR CHANGE IN ANY WAY):

```
def raw_data():

    # Define the possible ways the object can move and turn
    moves = ['Move forward', 'Move & turn left', 'Move & turn right']
    # Define the possible initial orientations
    directions = ['North', 'North east', 'South east',
                  'South', 'South west', 'North west']

    # Choose the number of moves
    num_moves = randint(0, 10)
    # Choose the object's initial energy level
    # (which mustn't exceed the number of moves)
    energy = randint(0, num_moves)
    # Choose the object's initial orientation
    direction = choice(directions)

    # Keep track of how many moves have been created in total
    move_no = 0

    # Initialise the data set with the special first move
    random_moves = [[move_no, energy, direction]]

    # Create the remaining moves
    while move_no < num_moves:
        # Increment move number
        move_no = move_no + 1
        # Choose which way the object moves and turns
        move = choice(moves)
        # Add the new move to the data set
        random_moves.append([move_no, move])

    # Print the whole data set to the shell window, laid out
    # nicely, one move per line
    print("The moves to visualise are:\n")
    print(str(random_moves).replace('],', '],\n'))
    
    # Return the data set to the caller
    return random_moves
```

UNEDITABLE CODE FROM MY FILE THAT IMPORTS data_source.py (CANNOT EDIT OR CHANGE IN ANY WAY):

```
if isfile('data_source.py'):
    print('Data generation module found ...\n')
    from data_source import raw_data
    def data_set(new_seed = randint(0, 99999)):
        print('Using random number seed', new_seed, '...\n')
        seed(new_seed) # set the seed
        return raw_data() # return the random data set
else:
    print('No data generation module available ...\n')
    def data_set(dummy_parameter = None):
        return []

#this code is then executed via (THIS IS NOT EDITABLE):
visualise_data(data_set())
#with my code being under the function visualize data
```

MY CODE INSIDE FUNCTION visualise_data() (EDITABLE)

```
def data_drawing_loop(): #This is called inside function visualise data
    #defining values
    movement = data_set #have also tried random_moves = raw_data 
    running = True
    x = xcor()
    y = ycor()
    #check start direction, align
    heading = movement([0][2]) #WHERE I GET THE ERROR
    heading_Tru_Fal = False
    for direction in heading:
        if direction == 'North':
            heading_as_a_number = 90 
        ...
def visualise_data(raw_data):
    data_drawing_loop()
```

I cant seem to figure out why this error keeps occurring or if I've overlooked something simple.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT. MY CHILDREN ARE ALREADY SLEEPING (Constrains on how easy is to make them fall asleep again if they wake up)

Comment: `visualise_data(data_set())` ... you can see the data is passed as a parameter of `visualize_data`, which you haven't shared. Please share a [mcve] that shows what `data_set` is and how `visualize_data` is defined. `movement([0][2])` is very misleading syntax... you're calling `movement` as a function and passing in `[0][2]`, which is clearly out of bounds (define an array `[0]` and take the 3rd element of it... it only has one!). Did you mean `movement[0][2]`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hint: where the code says `def visualise_data(raw_data):`, what do you think the `(raw_data)` part of that line means? Can you think of a way to use this for the rest of the code?

Comment: @ggorlen what do you mean 'out of bounds' the list generated by raw data has a first element and a 3rd element within the first element?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel :\ .... cant believe I overlooked that...know exactly whats going wrong now ahha

Comment: @MEGAtron Please re-read my explanation. When you use parentheses, that's treated as a function call: `something()`. Functions can have arguments, like lists. Here's passing a 1-element list containing the value 0 as its only element to a function: `something([0])`. Now, if you create a list like `[0]`, you can index into it immediately: `[0][2]` is out of bounds because you're trying to get the 3rd element of the list `[0]`, which is a single-element list. `something[0][2]` is totally different, it's "get the 0th element of the first list, then get the 2nd element of the inner list"

Comment: Looks like `data_drawing_loop()` needs an argument, `def data_drawing_loop(raw_data):`, then call it with `data_drawing_loop(raw_data)`. After you do that, you'll probably get an error to the `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` which I explained in my first 2 comments. Remove the `()`s if you're just trying to index. I suggest you read up on functions, return values and scope in a basic Python tutorial. Then read about lists and 2d lists. All of your questions will be answered.